# What is the best approach to implement two bundles with common entities in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, bundle

I need two bundles that share some entities. What would be the best approach to implement this ?

I was thinking creating a third bundle that would just include the entities and then using them from within the other 2 bundles, but I'm not sure is this is the best approach...

Thanks

Comment: I guess you're looking for a [target entity listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html)

Comment: So you are suggesting picking one of the bundles and put the entities there and from the other one referencing the entities of that bundle ? I think the problem with this is that if I want to deploy just the secondary bundle I'd need to take the first bundle completely (with all the extra functionality)...

Comment: No. The purpose of the target entity listener is to decouple an entity from another one (e.g. Another namespace). In your *"main"* bundle (the one you don't want a dependency on the other one), you create the interface you need as an entity reference. Then you implement this interface into your *"sub"* bundle entity. This will let your main bundle unaware of the sub bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too suggest introducing a new bundle to store common entities. Let's say you have two bundles called A and B which have p,q,r entities in common. Introduce another bundle called C and place those p,q,r entities there. So both A and B can reuse those entities without any problem. Another great feature can be achieved by doing this is, you can easily remove A/B bundles without affecting the functionality of the system. But if you have uni-directional/bi-directional relationships, such as pointing from entities p,q,r to any entity in A/B bundle, you can't simply remove those bundles (removing from app kernal and routing). You have to remove the relationship from those entities at first place in order to remove a bundle. I just mentioned the significance of relationship types when it comes to bundle dependency.

So, the bottom line is, use another Bundle to store common entities to avoid duplication and reduce bundle dependability. I would recommend organising bundles according to the functionality of your project, in an independent way is one of the best approach.

Hope this helps,
Cheers!

Comment: Should I use bundle inheritance ? I could inherit from the bundle with the entities.

Comment: Yes you could inherit. That's not a problem as Symfony 2 provide convenient bundle inheritance. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html